# CountDownTimer not working properly

Tags: android, countdowntimer

```
for (int i=0; i<HisXArray.size(); i++) {
            ycoord2 = HisYArray.get(i);
            major2 = HisMajorArray.get(i);
            xcoord2 = HisXArray.get(i);
            minor2 = HisMinorArray.get(i);
            time3 = TimeArray.get(i);
            timer = new CountDownTimer(time3, 1000) {

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    Log.e("Timer", xcoord2 + " " + ycoord2 + " " + time3);
                    mView.mFadePaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    mView.drawOval(mView.mCanvas, xcoord2, ycoord2, 2*major2, 2*minor2, mView.mFadePaint);
                    mView.invalidate();
                }
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            }.start();
```

When I'm trying to draw something using timer, onFinish called only when time3 = 0 and when i = HisXArray.size() - 1, i.e. the last.

Answer (score 0):

Implement any intermediate steps in `onTick()`. [By design](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html), `onFinish()` is only called when the countdown is complete.